# Flash & Visual Studio [Form Design]

Tags: forms, visual-studio, flash

I'm developing a desktop application using Visual Studio, in c++ and c#. I managed to hide form edges and make custom ones but that's not what I really want.
The problem is: I would like to make the form window look better, and by that I mean completely different from the basic one.

Example: I would like to draw and script some advanced randomic moving swarm of dark pixels that actually are the edges of the visual studio form window.
Example 2: When you move your cursor over the swarmy pixels (the edges of the form) they change color or they react in some way.
I'm NOT asking you how to do actually do this examples.. I'm just want to know what is the best way to learn to accomplish this.
You can imagine this examples "easily" done in a online web-flash enviroment, that was the first thing I thought, but I'm talking about a desktop application, not about a flash site. So the question is:
Should I learn flash and actionscript and then find a way to implement that in visual studio? Or should I use some external graphical API that has nothing to do with flash? Or is it scriptable in c#/c++?

P.S. I can learn everything because I have time, I'm just deciding the best way to do that. Can you help me? Thanks in advance and sorry for my not so strong english.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this website meet your every need.
[Amethyst Tutorials](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Amethyst-Tutorials/article/how-to-add-swfs-to-net)